# facebook app is not recognizing extended permissions when asking user to authenticate

Tags: facebook, permissions

Please see attached screenshots. I've configured permissions for publish_actions (and also publish_stream) and I'm getting error message: requires extended permissions when I try to authenticate the application.  What's strange is that these permissions are not requested when the user is asked to authenticate.

[image: permissions]

[image: error]

cheers

Paul

Comment: Ohnotagain … http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12126253/mvc4-oauth-facebook-accessing-user-friend-permissions/12139992#12139992

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Permissions asked in App Settings --> Permissions --> 'Configure your permissions' section are only displayed in App Center or when using Auth Referrals. For permissions to be displayed during normal authentication flow (in permission dialog), you need to ask them using the 'scope' parameter in your code (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/). Hope that helps.